# Not able to see the roughness on the non-metallic parts of the model, it looks correct in don mccurdy gltf viewer. What am I missing?

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, gltf

I have a model with some parts of it being metallic and others non-metallic. I have applied the environment map to get the correct reflections from the metallic parts of the model but the non metallic parts look equally reflective.

What should I do to make the non-metallic parts to appear less reflective and more rough as they are created. The model looks perfect in the Don Muccurdy’s gltf-viewer.

Please tell me what parameters do I need to change to get it right?

First is my rendered model and Second is the gltf viewer rendered model.

[image: My rendered model]

[image: Don Mccurdy model]

```
var rgbeLoader=new THREE.RGBELoader().setType( THREE.UnsignedByteType )
.setPath( 'textures/equirectangular/' )
.load( 'pedestrian_overpass_2k.hdr', function ( texture ) {
    cubeGenerator = new THREE.EquirectangularToCubeGenerator( texture, { resolution: 1024 } );
    cubeGenerator.update( renderer );
    pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( cubeGenerator.renderTarget.texture );
    pmremGenerator.update( renderer );
    pmremCubeUVPacker = new THREE.PMREMCubeUVPacker( pmremGenerator.cubeLods );
    pmremCubeUVPacker.update( renderer );
    envMap = pmremCubeUVPacker.CubeUVRenderTarget.texture;
    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load( 'tfsProject4.glb', function ( gltf ) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    gltf.scene.traverse((e)=>{
        e.material.envMap=envMap;
    });
});
```

The following code is called from a function after loading all the assets including the model shown.

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

modalCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, modalCanHolder.width() / 
modalCanHolder.height(), 0.001, 100 );
var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1 );

scene.add( light );

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x808080 ); 

scene.add( light );

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, .3 );

directionalLight.position.set(0,10,10)

scene.add( directionalLight );


modalRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha:true});

modalRenderer.gammaOutput = true;

modalRenderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;

modalRenderer.physicallyCorrectLights=true;

modalRenderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding; 

modalRenderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;

modalRenderer.setSize( modalCanHolder.width(), modalCanHolder.height() );

modalRenderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

modalCanHolder.append( modalRenderer.domElement );

modalRenderer.domElement.id = 'modalCanvas';



cubeGenerator.update( modalRenderer );

pmremGenerator.update( modalRenderer );

pmremCubeUVPacker.update( modalRenderer );

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( modalCamera, modalRenderer.domElement );



var prod=products[id];

scene.add(prod);    


controls.update();


const animate = function () {

    subAnimation=requestAnimationFrame( animate );

     controls.update();

    modalRenderer.render( scene, modalCamera );

};

animate();
```

Please help me get the rendering right.

Comment: Maybe try increasing the amount of roughness on the non-metallic parts?